# GPG "NO_PUBKEY" errors for Libreoffice and Mozilla PPAs

Tags: 11.10, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Ever since installing Ubuntu 11.10, I've been having trouble adding PPAs to my Software Sources. In the past I could add PPAs using the usual "ppa:appName/ppa" syntax in the Software Sources and it would automatically retrieve the key from Launchpad, etc.

Now I have to manually add the key using apt-key, and even this sometimes doesn't work, as in the case of the LibreOffice and Mozilla Stable PPAs. See errors below:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1015216E75198A89
```

Is there a reason why keys do not get automatically retrieved any more? Can I fix this without doing a system reinstall?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appName/ppa` in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 83FBA1751378B444
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 1015216E75198A89
```

- [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: Care to elaborate? You shouldn't try to make users trust keys without any comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, this seems to be an issue regarding my means of connecting to my college Wi-Fi. As my laptop's wireless card is broken, I'm using my Android phone as a Wi-Fi tether, which seems to play havoc with the campus firewall. Browsing, etc. using the usual ports (80, 443, etc.) works, but adding keyservers and SSH'ing, etc. doesn't.

I confirmed this by connecting through 3G instead of Wi-Fi and the keys got automatically retrieved as usual.

Many thanks to those who have commented trying to help.